# Create a Virtual Mchine using KVM virsh commande

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization

I tried to create a VM using kvm (libvirt) virsh commande but the installation isn't completed. I used ubuntu server 22.04 lts and I didn't have acces to the console of the virtual machine . I don't use a desktop os and I can't use virt-manager. So is it possible to create a machine using virsh commande on a server directly without having desktop or no ? If it is possible where is my problem so ?
[here an image of the commandes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ZpwG.png)

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text. Cut and paste the text into the body of the question. This way nothing is cut off, it can be searched and is easier to read.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. Your problem is in the graphics. I have never used the spice method, so don't know how to help with that. I use the vnc method and connect via vnc from another computer to complete the installation: `--video=vmvga --graphics vnc,listen=0.0.0.0 --noautoconsole`

Comment: @David Ahh sorry I'm a new contributer and I didn't know that thing. Thanks for the advice I’ll take it into consideration for the next few times !

Comment: @DougSmythies I tried to use Vnc but it didn't work with me I don't know why. I get this error " The attempt to connect to the server failed. "

Comment: Please edit your question adding your most recent `virsh-install` command line attempt. I don't think it makes any difference, but I don't use `sudo` with `virt-install`.